# Solve trigonometric equation $ \cot x + \cos x = 1 + \cot x \cos x $

Tags: trigonometry

Solve trigonometric equation: $$ \cot (x) + \cos (x) = 1 + \cot (x) \cos (x) $$
I tried to multiply both sides with $\sin x$ (which I'm not sure if I can multiply with sin).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$(\cot x-1)(\cos x-1)=0$$

$\cos x=1=\cos0\implies x=2m\pi\pm0=2m\pi$ where $m$ is any integer

$\cot x=1\iff\tan x=1=\tan\dfrac\pi4\implies x=n\pi+\dfrac\pi4$ where $n$ is any integer

Comment: Dear sir, how did you figure it out so fast that you can write it like this $(\cot x−1)(\cos x−1)$?

Comment: @Gjekask practice, practice, practice...after some time you just "see" things like this. One possible way including some steps between: $$\cot(x)+\cos(x)=1+\cot(x)\cos(x)\Leftrightarrow a+b=1+ab \Leftrightarrow a+b-ab-1=0.$$ As we have $a$ and $b$ as well as $ab$ one might think of finding a factorization and applying a similar method as Vieta's formulas we can easily find $$a+b-ab-1=-(a-1)(b-1).$$

Answer (score 2):

> $$ \cot x + \cos x = 1 + \cot x \cos x $$

$$ \cot x + \cos x - 1 - \cot x \cos x =0$$

$$-( \cos x -1) (\cot x - 1) =0 $$

$$( \cos x -1) (\cot x - 1) =0 $$

Can you finish from here?

Answer (score 2):

Notice, we have $$\cot x+\cos x=1+\cot x\cos x$$
$$\frac{\cos x}{\sin x}+\cos x=1+\frac{\cos x}{\sin x}\cos x $$
$$\cos x+\sin x\cos x=\sin x+\cos^2 x $$
$$\cos x+\sin x\cos x-\sin x-\cos^2 x=0 $$
$$\underbrace{\cos x-\sin x}+\underbrace{\sin x\cos x-\cos^2 x}=0 $$

$$(\cos x-\sin x)-\cos x(\cos x-\sin x)=0 $$
$$(1-\cos x)(\cos x-\sin x)=0 $$
$$1-\cos x=0\vee \cos x-\sin x=0$$
$$\cos x=1\vee \sin x=\cos x\iff \tan x=1$$
$$x=2k\pi\vee x=k\pi+\frac{\pi}{4}$$
For all, $k$ is any integer

Comment: Can you tell me when can we multiply by sinus, or any other trigonometric function.

Comment: Are you asking about multiplication like this $$\sin^2A-\sin^2B=\sin(A-B)\sin(A+B)$$

Comment: No, how did you come at third row from second row, what did you do to both sides of second row (at your solution)?  Did you multiply both sides with $\sin x $?

Comment: Ok, It is similar to the multiplication of rational numbers